# How can I embed / reference .NET references in a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a .net resource library which contains some nuget packages as well as some default .net references:

- `NLog` (nuget)
- `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing` (.net reference)
- `System.Windows.Interactivity` (.net reference)

If I build my nuget package

`nuget pack -Prop Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory nuget %SOLUTION%\%SOLUTION%\%SOLUTION%.csproj`

and install it afterwards in a wpf project, the two .net references where not installed.

Is there a solution to automatically install the .net references?

Comment: Have you declared your dependencies as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element)?

Comment: Actually I use the `pack` command which does not need any dependency declaration. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack

Comment: "frameworkAssemblies: A collection of zero or more <frameworkAssembly> elements identifying .NET Framework assembly references that this package requires, which ensures that references are added to projects consuming the package." from @DominicJonas link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bradbury mentioned, I haved created a *.nuspec file and added all `framework assemblies` into it.

To automatically add these items to the nuspec without thinking about it, I have extended my personal `nugetLib` with a new function.

Now I have just a 1 liner in my ci script:

```
    # add framework assembly dependencies into the nuspec file
    - nugetlib frameworkassemblies -c %SOLUTION%\%SOLUTION%\%SOLUTION%.csproj -n %SOLUTION%\%SOLUTION%\%SOLUTION%.nuspec -p %SOLUTION%\%SOLUTION%\packages.config
```

Source: https://github.com/dojo90/nugetLib